# ClickOnce and app.config not deploying

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

I have a new WinForms application that I'm trying to deploy with the ClickOnce method.  However, the app.config file that is needed for the application is not included with the installation.

The application is installed properly from the server, and launches the exe, but as soon as I try to login by hitting my WCF Server, I get.

"Could not find the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Adminstrator\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\7KAA3h20\app.config"

I can manually copy the file from my development machine to this folder and the application works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The application settings are included in the ClickOnce application as yourappname.exe.config. Are you accessing the app.config through a different mechanism that the global app settings?

Answer (score 0):

Config file is included by default. Are you removing it for some reason?

You can choose files to be deployed on properties page (application files) if you are using Visual Studio.
If file is not in the list, you can add it to project and set build action to "Content" and it will show up in this list.